# Python Two dimensional condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am unsure how to phrase a conditional loop. I would like to create a NxN array consisting of elements which are equal to either 1 or -1. I have created a 3x3 array to begin with, which when printed consists of numbers between 0 and 1.

```
col = 3
row = 3

mymatrix = np.random.rand(col,row)
```

I would like to set their values to either 1 or -1, depending on whether the value they have been assigned is greater than or equal to 0.5.

```
for i in range(0,2): 
    for j in range(0,2):
        if mymatrix[i,j] <= 0.5:
            mymatrix[i,j] = -1.0
        elif mymatrix[i,j] >= 0.5:
            mymatrix[i,j] = 1.0

print mymatrix
```

For some reason, this prints a 3x3 matrix with only the inner 4 elements as 1 or -1.

```
[[-1, 1,0.19343979] 
 [ 1, -1, 0.59891168]  
 [ 0.02766664, 0.73244162, 0.41541223]]
```

I know that `mymatrix[2,2]` is 0.41541223, so I cannot understand why this is not being looped through.

Comment: Any reason to not use: `np.where(mymatrix <= 0.5, -1, 1)` ?

Comment: Anyway - the reason is that `range(0, 2)` will give `0` and `1` - the end is not included... so you'd want `range(0, 3)` or since the start parameter is assumed to be 0, you can use `range(3)`... Although, instead of hard coding, you should use `for i in range(row)... for j in range(col)`. Ultimately though - don't loop - use `np.where`

Comment: Ah, you're right. Out of curiosity why is this so? If the further element to the right and the bottom is mymatrix[2,2], then why is it that 3 is not out of range?

Comment: What does `print list(range(3))` show you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your Problem

You need to loop over all rows and columns:

```
for i in range(row): 
    for j in range(col):
```

You only loop over the first two:

```
col = 3
row = 3
```

In Python `range(start, end)` gives a range starting form `start` inclusive and `end` exclusive.

```
for i in range(0,2): 
    for j in range(0,2):
```

BTW, in Python rows are the first dimension so this would be better:

```
mymatrix = np.random.rand(row, col)
```

even though both `row` and `col` have the same value in your case.

### Better Solution

Working with NumPy arrays, you should avoid loops as much as possible,
because loops can be really slow. To my experience those loops over NumPy arrays can be even slower than loops over Python lists.
Therefore, better do:

```
np.where(mymatrix <= 0.5, -1, 1)
```

This is a vectorized version that is much faster.
One of the goals using NumPy is often speed.

> `where(condition, [x, y])`
>
> Return elements, either from `x` or `y`, depending on `condition`.

Comment: Works great and is much faster even when I use very large values for N

Comment: Great. Glad to be helpful.

Comment: @Grace The other option of course is since you're after -1 or 1 and the criteria is effectively 50/50 to just use np.random.choice([-1, 1], (3, 3))

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in upper bound:

```
mymatrix = np.random.rand(col,row)

for i in range(0,3): 
    for j in range(0,3):
        if mymatrix[i,j] <= 0.5:
            mymatrix[i,j] = -1.0
        elif mymatrix[i,j] >= 0.5:
            mymatrix[i,j] = 1.0

print (mymatrix)
```